# Macro for deleting values from certain columns in a row based on a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I'm trying to find a way to delete values from certain columns within a row based on a cell value. I've found a few guides on deleting entire rows based on a cell value, but not partial rows.

We have case UPCs and consumer UPCs. For this spreadsheet, we need to delete weight, cost, and retail for all case UPCs (this information is generated from a reporting program, but needs to be deleted because it is not relevant to the users). For consumer UPCs, this data is relevant and needs to be kept.

I want to build a separate excel sheet that has a list of case UPCs, and create a macro that will refer to this list and delete the values from columns D through F if it is a case UPC. Any ideas for going about this, or tips?

Before example:

[image: Before Table]

After example:

[image: After Table]

Comment: This is an [hint for the macro](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/543798-finding-number-coloring-cell-he.html). You needn't a macro: you may add a _temporary working column_, [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Look-up-values-in-a-list-of-data-c249efc5-5847-4329-bfee-ecffead5ef88) if the value C is present in the other sheet, then do a white on white conditional formatting in the cells DEF related to the value of the _working column_. Then, when you'll update the cost/weight, you may manually delete the value of the working column or the entry in the other sheet.

Comment: Don't do white on white conditional formatting, because white prints as black. If you go down that route, have ";;;" as a custom number format instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd structure this:

[image: Screenshot]
** Blue cells are hardcoded values, black cells are formulas.*

- `D2` has a simple formula:

  `=NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,$L$2:$L$7,0)))`

  Copy that down all the way to your last row.

  .
- `E2` has an even simpler formula, repeated all the way through column `G`:

  `=$D2*H2`

**EDIT** -- 
Forgot to mention that column `E` has number format: `0.00" lbs";;General` and column `F` and `G` should have number format: `$0.00;;General`, despite what the screenshot shows.

Comment: @MeganPeters you're welcome! I added a small note to the bottom of my answer regarding number formats. Let me know if you have questions with that. And in case this answers your question appropriately, please take a moment to upvote the answer and mark it as accepted! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I have. I modified the formula in E through G to give me blanks instead of 0 values:

Comment: The formula in E(sorry can't figure out how to edit my previous comment): =IF(D2=TRUE,H2,"")

Comment: @MeganPeters superuser.com (or any other stack exchange site) only lets you edit your comments before N amount of seconds.